# Improve AJAX response handling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, ajax

This code handles a response from an RSS feed. It organizes and appends to content. If there's a video embeded then separate it from the rest of the content. I would like a review mainly on performance/efficiency but I'm open to any other suggestions as well. That star selector is really nagging me but I don't know of a better way to iterate over all the contained elements.

```
function getFeed(url, element, callback) {
    $.getJSON("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q="+encodeURIComponent(url), function(response) {
        var content = "",
            $element = $(element);

        for (var i = 0; i < response.responseData.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            content = content + response.responseData.feed.entries[i].content; //Join all the feed entries
        }

        $element.find(".content").html(content).addClass($element.find("embed").length? "withVideo" : "");

        $element.find("*").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.removeAttr("style width align"); //Reset all the crap that comes with the response

            if ($this.is("embed")) {
                $element.append("<div class='video'></div>");
                $this.attr("width", 640).attr("height", 360).parent().appendTo(element + " .video");
            };
        });

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback();
        };
    });
}
```

This is then called like so:

```
getFeed("http://www.kent.k12.wa.us/site/RSS.aspx?PageID=3854", "#TechExpo", optionalCallback);
```

Here's what a response might look like

```
<div width="500" style="whatever"><p>Some text blah blah blah.</p>
<p align="right">Some more text</p>
</div>
<div><h2>Video Title</h2>
<embed src="http://..." width="360" height="202" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
<small>Watch the 7th annual Tech Expo highlights.</small></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Late reply,

this code is good, I can only find 2 faults:

1. Your code should have error handling for the JSON call, things can go wrong
2. Too much horizontal stretching, I would introduce some sugar for this:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < response.responseData.feed.entries.length; i++) {
       content = content + response.responseData.feed.entries[i].content; //Join all the feed entries
   }
   ```

   could be

   ```
   var entries = response.responseData.feed.entries;
   for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
       content = content + entries[i].content; //Join all the feed entries
   }
   ```

   Also, I find

   ```
   $element.find(".content").html(content)
                            .addClass($element.find("embed").length? "withVideo" : "");
   ```

   more readable.

As for `find("*")`, it seems to be cleanest way to access all children.